# How to open and split multiple files

Tags: vim

How can I open in a split window multiple files. One split for each file if I'm not being clear.

I want to do something like. `:sp app/views/*.erb` and have the ~7 files all open in their own split windows.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just learned from tonymec@#vim that you can do

```
:args app/views/*.erb | all
```

for horizontal splits or

```
:args app/views/*.erb | vertical all
```

for vertical.

Comment: Works. Would you please explain how this works? Got no clue why I need to use "args. Expansion to use a new tab for this would be appreciated to (idk how to "pass" the `:tab` modifier to all)

Comment: I got the code from someone back then and I've never delved deep into how it works. If you figure it out (maybe using `:help args` and so on), please share in a comment! :)

Comment: Explanation: vim remembers all files opened at start-up. This is called the argslist. Even if you open other files from within vim, the argslist remains the same. Here, the argslist is set from withing vim, with `args` (see args_f). Next (it is the next command since we use a bar to separate it (see :bar)) we use `all` to see all files in the argslist at once. Vim used to only have a horizontal split (just easier to implement), so splits are by default a horizontal split. That's why `vertical` exists, which just executes a command but replaces horizontal splitting with vertical splitting.

Answer (score 63):

Not actually from within vim, but perhaps you can run vim like this:

```
vim -o app/views/*.erb
```

Comment: And `-O` instead of `-o` for vertical splitting.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with more than two files. Using `-o` or `-O` with three files: the first file opens twice, the second file once, and the third file doesn't open. Vim 7.4.

Comment: Working fine on Vim 7.3.429

Comment: Is is possible to make vim do this by default? Current I have an alias which does this.

Comment: Works for me in vim 7.4.629 and vim 7.3.646.  Very nice, thank you.

Answer (score 23):

```
vim -O app/views/*.erb
```

This is also from the shell. It will open as vertical splits.

Answer (score 3):

What happens when you do a

```
:sf app/views/*.erb
```

from within vim?

Comment: works for me on Mac. But I was trying to do vertically. from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32399791/sf-in-vim-but-split-vertically I fount it would be  :vert sf <filename>

Answer (score 1):

Had to whip up a function.

```
  fun! OpenSplits(dir)
    for f in split(glob(a:dir), '\n')
      execute "sp " f
    endfor
  endfun
```