# Split and find file in Vim like :sf but vertically

Tags: vim

I use `:sf <filename>` with Vim a lot, to split horizontally and edit the said file in the new window.

I wonder what's the equivalent command to do the same but split vertically rather than horizontally.

`:vne` seems the closest I can find to this, but the help says it doesn't search for the file like `:sf` does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
:vert sf <filename>
```

From `:h :vert`:

```
                        *:vert* *:vertical*
:vert[ical] {cmd}
        Execute {cmd}.  If it contains a command that splits a window,
        it will be split vertically.
        Doesn't work for |:execute| and |:normal|.
```

Note: The usual way of describing the 'direction' of a split (vertical/horiontal) is by the axis of the split, not the layout of the windows, so you're actually looking for a vertical split here.

Comment: Thanks, it makes better sense now. `:vert sf` is a bit long and I was hoping for something like `:vsf` but anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thanks for that note, I've just updated my question to use v instead of h. Thanks again.

Comment: @bjfletcher: You could use `:cabbrev vsf vertical splitfind`, altough then any time you type `vsf<space>` in command mode it'll be expanded to `vertical splitfind` (though you're probably not typing `vsf` in another context all that often).

Comment: cool, 4 or 5 extra characters really isn't that big a deal when I'll be doing it only once every now and then. Thanks for your answer & helpful comments.

Comment: @Marth be careful with simple `cabbrev`'s as they expand in unexpected places. e.g. `/`, `<c-r>=`, and `input()`'s. See `getcmdtype()` for a list. You can roll your own via an [expression mapping](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7515418/438329) or use [cmdalias.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=746).  Example of expression mapping: `cnoreabbrev <expr> vsf getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == 'vsf' ? 'vert sf' : 'vsf'`

Answer (score 2):

```
:sp filename
```

Splits the screen horizontally

```
:vsp filename
```

Splits the screen vertically

Comment: When I said horizontally, I meant windows on the left and right, rather than on the top and bottom. Was I meant to say vertically? `:sp` I see is top and bottom.

Comment: That's great, very close now :) you have `sp` and `vsp` there, great, and if you can put in `sf` and `???` too then this would be the answer I wanted. I'll upvote and accept. :)

Comment: I answered this question on mobile platform. I don't know how to format it. I can't even test the commands :( Thanks for sf and ???. I didn't know these commands :D

Comment: I usually type the answers in Vim and then post here. But, now I don't have access to vim and I've to type the answer slowly on this lousy mobile platform.